# Kivy dynamically replace kv file and add .widget

Tags: python, model-view-controller, kivy

Here i'm trying to refresh the screen based on a variable named "view". The goal is to load the header and footer and the requested view (page)
The view doesn't change when i call View('example') but all prints works well.

What i am missing? I'm new with python and kivy so if there is something that already exists for that, i'll take it :)

main .py

```
import kivy
import runpy
import re
import pathlib
from kivy.app import App
from libraries.env import env
from App.Controllers.Controller import View

class App(App):

    route = ""
    params = {}

    def build(self):
        return View('home')

    #Parse routes.py and load the required controller
    def route(self, route, params=None):
        filepath = 'routes.py'
        controller = ""
        controllerClass = ""
        action = ""
        with open(filepath) as fp:
            for line_num, line in enumerate(fp):
                splitted = re.split('=|@', line)
                if splitted[0] == route :
                    controller = splitted[1].replace('"', '')
                    controllerClass = controller.split('/')[-1]
                    action = splitted[2].replace('"', '').replace('\n', '')
        if controller:
            runpy.run_path(controller + '.py', run_name='__index__')
        else:
            print("Le controller pour la route " + route + " est introuvable.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

App/Controllers/HomeController.py

```
from App.Controllers.Controller import View

class HomeController():
    
    def index(self):
        print('Controller : HomeController => index')
        return View("home")

if __name__=='__index__':
    HomeController().index()
```

App/Controllers/Controller.py

```
import pathlib
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class View(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, view, **kwargs):
        print('View : pages/' + view + '.kv')
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.add_widget(Builder.load_file("App/Views/partials/header.kv"))
        p = pathlib.Path('App/Views/pages/'+view+'.kv')
        if p.is_file():
            self.add_widget(Builder.load_file("App/Views/pages/"+view+".kv"))
            print("Chargement de la vue ok.")
        else:
            print("La vue " + view + " est introuvable.")
        self.add_widget(Builder.load_file("App/Views/partials/footer.kv"))
```

More globally I'm trying to learn python (I come from PHP). I train by making a small home-made framework. The work in progress is available here :
https://github.com/mchev/Larathon

Answer (score 0):

> The view doesn't change when i call View('example') but all prints works well.

That's because this instantiates a new `View` but doesn't do anything with it, so your code runs but you don't display the result anywhere.

Presumably you intended to run some code on an existing View, not a new one like this. Post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem if you can't work out how to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the post and added a link to the complete project.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck with an illustrative example, not a whole project.